# Angular.js and Play Framework 2.1 Integration with helper functions

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.1

I want to use Angular.js with the Play Framework [view helper functions](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper) (e.g @helper.form(...))

How do I insert an Angular directive (e.g: ng-controller)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure you discovered, you can't directly make a Scala `Symbol` with a dash like `'some-word`. Instead, just wrap it:

```
scala> Symbol("ng-controller")
res4: Symbol = 'ng-controller
```

Answer (score 1):

We're currently using Play Framework 2 and AngularJS.

We added a special method to handle this:

```
implicit class SymbolString( str: String ) {
    def s = Symbol(str)
  }
```

And then we just call it as such:

```
"ng-model".s -> "datasetName"
```

Comment: Where did you add your implicit method?

Comment: We added it into a `Utils.scala` file which resides in the controllers folder. Looks like this: `package controllers

object Utils {

  implicit class SymbolString( str: String ) {
    def s = Symbol(str)
  }
}
`

Comment: And then include it, of course, in the view where you need to use it, like so: `@import Utils._`